# HTML Web Form store Data

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've got a Web Form and I wanted to know how I can store those Usernames/Passwords, so when someone goes to the page, and logs in, I want to know what information he used to access the Page.

My HTML Code: http://pastebin.com/ths6vWkV

- Coto

Comment: Post your code here.  Don't make people go off-site in order to help you.

Comment: Your workings for this will need to be a little more than just HTML.  Post your code, but only the important parts here.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done client-side only. You will need a server-side application running to handle this type of input. I'm not a PHP guy myself, but many cheap web hosting services offer PHP support. Once you are set up with PHP, try looking at this section of the official PHP manual titled [Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

Example HTML:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Example PHP after form is submitted:

```
Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
You are <?php echo (int)$_POST['age']; ?> years old.
```

Example output:

> Hi Joe. You are 22 years old.